# iPhone : How to make transparent image on TouchesMoved event?

Tags: iphone, image, graphics, transparency, cgcontext

I already tried kCGBlendModeXOR but it turn black after the transparency.

Here my code that i done , but it not what I want.

```
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];  
  CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
  CGPoint lastPoint = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
  [imageView_skype.image drawInRect:rect];
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 36.0);
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  CGContextSetAlpha(context,0.10);

  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeXOR);

  CGContextBeginPath(context);

  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
  imageView_skype.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

your can use mask to do this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

in your touches moved event draw a mask image only black and white

and mask your original image

Comment: What want is on event touchesMoved I can get the pixel and make it to transparency. so I can display the background view.